# How do I free the standard icons and cursors (those loaded with LoadIcon/Cursor(NULL, IDI/IDC_WHATEVER))?

Tags: c, winapi

Another quick question this time: my DLL which handles UI stuff has an [`uninit()` function that should be called before the program terminates that frees all resources](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/20/763727.aspx) (unregisters window classes, deletes a private heap, etc.). What is the required call for unloading `IDI_APPLICATION`, `IDC_ARROW`, and other system icons and cursors loaded with `LoadIcon`/`Cursor(NULL, IDI`/`IDC_WHATEVER)`? The closest I can gather from MSDN is that `DeleteObject()` should not be called on these icons; is there no such function, in that case? Thanks.

Comment: If it is system loaded, you don't need `DeleteObject()`, if you use your own, delete when you're done with it.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. @KenWhite I'm already freeing temporary things immediately; this function is for things that are initialized at DLL startup and have to stay alive throughout the lifetime of the DLL, namely a private window, window classes, a GDI font object, and the DLL's private heap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't unload the system-defined icons or cursors. The [documentation for DestroyIcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), for instance, specifically says (**emphasis added**):

> It is only necessary to call *DestroyIcon* for icons and cursors created with the following functions: *CreateIconFromResourceEx* (if called without the LR_SHARED flag), *CreateIconIndirect*, and *CopyIcon*. **Do not use this function to destroy a shared icon. A shared icon is valid as long as the module from which it was loaded remains in memory.** The following functions obtain a shared icon.
>
> - LoadIcon
> - LoadImage (if you use the LR_SHARED flag)
> - CopyImage (if you use the LR_COPYRETURNORG flag and the hImage parameter is a shared icon)
> - CreateIconFromResource
> - CreateIconFromResourceEx (if you use the LR_SHARED flag)

The above clearly states that icons you obtain with LoadIcon() should not be destroyed. The same is said in the [documentation for DestroyCursor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648386%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Destroys a cursor and frees any memory the cursor occupied. **Do not use this function to destroy a shared cursor.**

Comment: Yes, I saw that; I was wondering if there was some other information I missed. Thanks for confirming otherwise!